# How to get JSON response from a service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have trying to get the PNR Status (Train Ticket status Information) from a service

## Request for Valid PNR

request format :http://www.mmtstraintimings.in/pnrstatus/{PNR Number}

[Service URL With Valid PNR : http://www.mmtstraintimings.in/pnrstatus/8102874012](http://www.mmtstraintimings.in/pnrstatus/8102874012)

Response :

"`Journey Details<\/td>\u000a<\/tr>\u000a<TR class=\"heading_table\">\u000a<td width=\"11%\">Train Number<\/Td>\u000a<td width=\"16%\">Train Name<\/td>\u000a<td width=\"18%\">Boarding Date <br>(DD-MM-YYYY)<\/td>\u000a<td width=\"7%\">From<\/Td>\u000a<td width=\"7%\">To<\/Td>\u000a<td width=\"14%\">Reserved Upto<\/Td>\u000a<td width=\"21%\">Boarding Point<\/Td>\u000a<td width=\"6%\">Class<\/Td>\u000a<\/TR>\u000a<TR>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\">*19309<\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\">GNC INDORE EXP <\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"> 3- 6-2012<\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\">BRC <\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\">INDB<\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\">INDB<\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\">BRC <\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"> SL<\/TD>\u000a<\/TR>\u000a<\/TABLE><table class='listings' border='0' id='listings'><tbody>\u000a<TR>\u000a<td width=\"25%\" class=\"heading_table_top\">S. No.<\/td>\u000a<td width=\"45%\" class=\"heading_table_top\">Booking Status <br \/> (Coach No , Berth No., Quota)<\/td>\u000a<td width=\"30%\" class=\"heading_table_top\">* Current Status <br \/>(Coach No , Berth No.)<\/td>\u000a<\/TR>\u000a<TR>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>Passenger 1<\/B><\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>W\/L  112,PQWL  <\/B><\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>W\/L   92<\/B><\/TD>\u000a<\/TR>\u000a<TR>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>Passenger 2<\/B><\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>W\/L  113,PQWL  <\/B><\/TD>\u000a<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>W\/L   93<\/B><\/TD>\u000a<\/TR>\u000a<TR>\u000a<td class=\"heading_table_top\">Charting Status<\/td>\u000a<TD colspan=\"3\" align=\"middle\" valign=\"middle\" class=\"table_border_both\"> CHART NOT PREPARED <\/TD>\u000a<\/TR>\u000a<TR>\u000a<td colspan=\"4\"><font color=\"#1219e8\" size=\"1\"><b> * Please Note that in case the Final Charts have not been prepared, the Current Status might upgrade\/downgrade at a later stage.<\/font><\/b><\/Td>\u000a<\/TR>\u000a<\/TABLE>\u000a<BR>\u000a<TABLE wi`"

Is this respose HTML or JSON or what ??? ijust cant get it.

I think its using Http POST to get the information.

A website consuming this service link http://www.pnrstatuscheck.in/ show the information in this format

[image: The above response is shown on the website as this image]

I would like to extract the information in to an entity and use it as i like..
how can I do that..

Any pointers would be helpful

## Edit

I even made a small program to get the above text (i still cant figure out how to interpret it)

Remove the proxy code if yo are not using a proxy

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mmtstraintimings.in/pnrstatus/8102874012");
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ID", "pass", "domain");
        request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("id", "pass", "domain");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: looks like a HTML response to me

Comment: There is no way that can be JSON. Unless am missing something

Comment: @JohnGathogo I agree with you... but then what is it ?? HTML ?? Those `\/` characters are unknown to me.....

Comment: @Kane If its HTML how would i interpet that cuz event the table tag at last is not properly closed. but if you can see the image the wesite that uises the service formats its properly

Comment: Looks like escaped HTML to me. The \u000a are newlines.

Comment: @NicoBeemster `Escaped HTML` any input on how to read this ??

Comment: Sure, a working link would definitely help though hehe ;-)

(this is an empty "resultset": http://www.mmtstraintimings.in/pnrstatus/8102874012)

Comment: @NicoBeemster I clicked the link (Posted by me and you in IE) i am getting save as dialog for a file (I save it as HTML) and open in IE to get the required info... (PNR is working one as its my ticket no and i havent travelled with that ticket yet ;) )

Comment: My guess is that the web service involved intends you to display this in a table.  Not only that but a table which is partially created (since the blob starts with a partial row definition).

Comment: Do they have a real web service API?  This is obviously targeted for human consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up the response a little for you.

Don't know what you'd possibly want to do with this, but since the response isn't complete you can't even parse it..

Also tested this in Fiddler with GET requests with both XML and JSON as accept types. No difference.

```
            "Journey Details</td>
</tr>

<TR class="heading_table">
    <td width="11%">Train Number</Td>
    <td width="16%">Train Name</td>
    <td width="18%">Boarding Date <br>(DD-MM-YYYY)</td>
    <td width="7%">From</Td>
    <td width="7%">To</Td>
    <td width="14%">Reserved Upto</Td>
    <td width="21%">Boarding Point</Td>
    <td width="6%">Class</Td>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD class="table_border_both">*19309</TD>
    <TD class="table_border_both">GNC INDORE EXP </TD>
    <TD class="table_border_both"> 3- 6-2012</TD>
    <TD class="table_border_both">BRC </TD>
    <TD class="table_border_both">INDB</TD>
    <TD class="table_border_both">INDB</TD>
    <TD class="table_border_both">BRC </TD>
    <TD class="table_border_both"> SL</TD>
</TR>
```

```
<table class='listings' border='0' id='listings'>
    <tbody>
        <TR>
            <td width="25%" class="heading_table_top">S. No.</td>
            <td width="45%" class="heading_table_top">Booking Status <br /> (Coach No , Berth No., Quota)</td>
            <td width="30%" class="heading_table_top">* Current Status <br />(Coach No , Berth No.)</td>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD class="table_border_both"><B>Passenger 1</B></TD>
            <TD class="table_border_both"><B>W/L  112,PQWL  </B></TD>
            <TD class="table_border_both"><B>W/L   91</B></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD class="table_border_both"><B>Passenger 2</B></TD>
            <TD class="table_border_both"><B>W/L  113,PQWL  </B></TD>
            <TD class="table_border_both"><B>W/L   92</B></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <td class="heading_table_top">Charting Status</td>
            <TD colspan="3" align="middle" valign="middle" class="table_border_both"> CHART NOT PREPARED </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <td colspan="4">
                <font color="#1219e8" size="1">
                    <b> * Please Note that in case the Final Charts have not been prepared, the Current Status might upgrade/downgrade at a later stage.</font></b>
            </Td>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <BR>
    <TABLE wi"
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this... cant i parse this if i add the required tags manually ... I wish get the information in a object..

Comment: I strongly discourage you to perform that:
- the response does not appear to be complete (not only structure, but also data)
- you would be "creating" your own data

I'd suggest asking for a valid webservice which you can consume.

But, if you really want to, you can parse this "data". If the structure of all responses is consistent it should not be a problem.